# deploying / starting flowable war file on tomcat server mac os

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, flowable

I am trying to deploy and start 2 WAR files flowable provides to check out the application.

I got Java 14 installed, Tomcat 10.x and Maven.

Added the 2 WAR files into the webapps folder of Tomcat and then I am running the ./startup.sh in the bin folder

If I tail the logs of the catalina.out file, I see that both WARs have been deployed and in the webapps folder 2 new folders have been created for both WARs and there are no errors.

On localhost:8080 Tomcat is started, but if I try to visit the webapps like localhost:8080/flowable-ui, I get a 404.

What am I missing? For some reason there are no errors, but also no webapp visible.

Comment: You can put the WARs in the `webapps-javaee` folder: Tomcat will convert them from Jakarta EE 8 to Jakarta EE 9.

Comment: Likely the application is using Jakarta EE 8 or earlier. Consider installing Tomcat 9 instead of Tomcat 10.